# Can we get a picture for the Space Exploration StackExchange site?

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be pretty nice if we had a picture, instead of the generic SX speech bubble.  I was thinking that we could have something simple, like just a rocketship, or we could go with a deep space probe or the Curiosity MSL rover.  In fact, if someone was dedicated to making a few icons, we could change it to whatever mission has an upcoming event.  For example, right now it could be Juno, in 2018 we could change to InSight or ExoMars, then in 2020 it would be Mars 2020, etc.

Comment: We don't get customizations until we graduate. For more info, see http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/716/what-is-the-status-of-space-ses-beta-rating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, not for a while. This will only happen when we have an average of 10 questions/day for an extended period of time, and "graduate". We're about half-way there.