# Now that the site has graduated, how do we get a site-specific icon?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

This old question about the same thing

[Can we get a picture for the Space Exploration StackExchange site?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/can-we-get-a-picture-for-the-space-exploration-stackexchange-site)

was answered by "wait until the site graduates".

Well, it has. Let's ditch the blue speech bubble and get something appropriate.

Comment: That would be nice.

Comment: The answer is on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326614/282094 - follow the last link in the answer, to a three year old post. That's the most recent and probably still applies, but the previous graphic designer left; might to roll your own, like Community ADs. --- Also, add the design tag to this question.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbsU5.jpg?s=64&g=1 - looks good to me ;)

Comment: @Mazura lol, but more Sputnik-y maybe? https://st2.depositphotos.com/4060975/8061/v/950/depositphotos_80618930-stock-illustration-sputnik-vector-icon.jpg

Comment: While it is true that "graduation" no longer implies getting a site-specific design (not even a proper icon), that doesn't mean you can't just [ask for it anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325487). Yes, they don't _have to_ make you one, but they _can_ allocate the resources if they deem it appropriate.

Comment: Things that I think helped Spanish.SE get their own icon (besides the obvious 2-sites-1-icon thing): 1. having one of their high-rep users ask for it _publicly_; 2. having their mods on board (they spoke with Catija in private too); 3. having their community show their support by discussing and voting for the new icon on their own Meta (10 votes on a Spanish. SE Meta question was quite a feat back then). If Space.SE manages to put the same energy into this... who knows -- it _might_ work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That information is out-of-date. Graduation is no longer accompanied by site design.

For more, see https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2881/58

Comment: Possibly having more say in company - community communications, which could be helped by more mods, maybe the company should care us enough well to give us one. Alternatively, we could provide some below a meta post, vote for them, and the company might be enough generous to do what we suggest.